# Debugging UpdateCursor TypeError?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, typeerror

I am trying to split a field which contains, e.g., 2-10 and get the 2. The print statement produces the value 2 which is what I expect. I am getting a TypeError:

TypeError: 'Row' object does not support item assignment

Where am I going wrong; it appears as though I am following documentation and other answers on stack exchange.

ArcGIS 10.3.1, Python 2.7

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature, ['CUT_YEAR1'])
for row in cursor:
    print str(int(round(int((((row.getValue("cut_period")).replace(" ", "")).split('-'))[0]))))
    row[0] = str(int(round(int((((row.getValue("cut_period")).replace(" ", "")).split('-'))[0]))))
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I'm amazed you get '2' at all. The cursor requests a field named *cut_year1*, yet you try to read value *cut_period* from the row. I think it's less complicated to simply get the first value from the row object. What about `row[0] = str(row[0]).split("-")[0].strip()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are confusing the syntax of arcpy.da.UpdateCursor with arcpy.UpdateCursor:

- arcpy.UpdateCursor: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/updatecursor.htm
- arcpy.da.UpdateCursor: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm

Use row.setValue as per the documentation for arcpy.UpdateCursor.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include links to ArcGIS Desktop help rather than ArcGIS Pro. While they are probably the same, there can be differences, particularly in code samples.

Comment: I ended up having to use this answer in combo with @Berend Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error `TypeError: 'Row' object does not support item assignment` is telling you that with an `arcpy.UpdateCursor()` you cannot assign values to the row items as you are trying to do with

```
row[0] = ...
```

This is valid syntax in an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`.  I would recommend you put your calculation into a new variable so you can print and update and only enter the calculation once (to keep it tidier).

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, ['CUT_YEAR1', 'cut_period']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cp = round(int(row[1].split('-')[0].replace(" ", ""))
        print cp
        row[0] = cp
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

If you still need to convert to string (I'm not sure you do need to) you can just put the `str()` tag around the variable:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, ['CUT_YEAR1', 'cut_period']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cp = round(int(row[1].split('-')[0].replace(" ", ""))
        print cp
        row[0] = str(cp)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```